# Perl `use qw` or import subroutines from pm files

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a perl module `.pm` file what containts my subroutines and it looks like this:

```
package test;
use strict;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT $ERROR $NAME);
require Exporter;
@ISA  = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = (
    sub1
    sub2
    err1
    err2
);
#...etc...
```

Now I have a `pl` file, what need to import subroutines, but not every one, only if they are in the configured list. For example:

```
@subs = ('sub1', 'sub2'); # need to load sub1 & sub2, but do not load err1 & err2
```

or

```
@subs = ('sub1', 'err1'); # need to load sub1 & err1, but do not load sub2 & err2
```

How can I do this?

I tried to do this, but not working:

```
my @subs = ('sub1', 'sub2');
use test @subs;
```

Is there any way to load only the needed functions? And what is needed is read from SQL or config file or any other way...

Comment: Modules import subs into other "namespaces" so they can be called by their declared name rather than *fully qualified*. So instead of trying to selectively import subs, refer to them by their full name. (Your snippet: `test::sub1()`, `test::sub2()`, etc.).

Comment: Also, `@EXPORT` exports all by default. So all subs are already at the underlying `pl` file's exposal. You can selectively *import* when the subs are in `@EXPORT_OK`.

Comment: @LinusKleen: If I use this full name, then load into the memory only the used functions?

Comment: No. You can `use` the module, then refer to its subs fully qualified. Exporting them only saves you from referring to the subs by their "full name".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason your code:

```
my @subs = ('sub1', 'sub2');
use test @subs;
```

doesn't work is that [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) statements are evaluated immediately during parsing, before (almost) any other code.  Thus, the second line of your code actually runs *before* the first one, and so `@subs` is still empty at that point.

This *would* work:

```
my @subs;
BEGIN { @subs = ('sub1', 'sub2'); }
use test @subs;
```

as would this:

```
BEGIN {
    my @subs = ('sub1', 'sub2');
    require test;
    test->import(@subs);
}
```

In the former version, the `BEGIN` block is used to make the assignment to `@subs` happen already during parsing; in the second version, the entire code is put inside a `BEGIN` block, and the `use` statement is replaced with its run-time equivalent (`require` + `import`).

---

However, you probably don't have any reason to do this in the first place.  When you load a module, *all* of its code is loaded anyway,<sup>*</sup> so you don't actually save any memory by just importing some of the functions the module provides.  In fact, just about the only real reason not to import everything a module provides is to avoid conflicts between modules that might be trying to export functions with the same name, or with your own function.

In any case, it's always<sup>*</sup> possible to call functions in a module without importing them at all, just by prefixing them with the module name and `::`.  So, instead of:

```
use test qw(foo bar);
foo();
bar();
```

you can just do:

```
use test ();
test::foo();
test::bar();
```

---

<sup>*) Technically, there are few things that are *guaranteed* in Perl, and it's quite possible for a module to implement some kind of a lazy-loading mechanism that only creates functions (or loads them from another module) when you import them.  But that requires a custom `import` (and/or `AUTOLOAD`) method; for ordinary modules using [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html), the simplified description above is true.</sup>

Comment: Thanks your answer. And the next question is how can I save memory and compiling time with perl modules and `use`? It is possible at all?

Comment: That might a subject for a separate question, but just to start with, see the [AutoLoader](http://perldoc.perl.org/AutoLoader.html) and [SelfLoader](http://perldoc.perl.org/SelfLoader.html) modules, and the ["Autoloading" section in perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, all Perl globals should use capital letters, so the name of your package should begin with capital letter, and the name of the file should be altered to agree

Secondly, there is much less overhead if, instead of *inheriting* from `Exporter`, you load its `import` method directly

I don't understand what sort of thing `err1` and `err2` are, but should put *optional* exports in the array `@EXPORT_OK`

That leaves your module looking like this

**Test.pm**

```
package Test;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT_OK = qw/ sub1 sub2 /;

sub sub1 {
  print "sub1\n";
}

sub sub2 {
  print "sub2\n";
}
```

and a program that uses it would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test qw/ sub1 /;

sub1;
```

**output**

```
sub1
```

Comment: This is all good advice, but I don't think it actually answers the OP's question. See my answer for what I believe is the actual issue the OP is facing.